# In QGIS, my contour layer is always in meters despite settings, and DEM

Tags: qgis, elevation, units

I have a DEM file in Raster Layer that has elevations in meters, I have used the Raster Calculator to convert them to feet, and saved as a new DEM layer. The legend shows feet. When I run an extraction > contour layer on that DEM (the one in feet) it comes out with contours in meters still. I know how to 'cheat' and show converted numbers in feet, but it's a real pain the get the actual contours to be in 1ft intervals, style the 5' lines, etc. I have changed all the Project Settings I can to feet, though I have not found anything that sets elevation to feet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67683/discussion-on-question-by-mick-in-qgis-my-contour-layer-is-always-in-meters-des).

Answer (score -1):

FYI to anyone in similar shape... it turned out to be something wrong with my installation of QGIS. Re-intalling it on a different machine led to none of the problems I encountered. Thanks.

Comment: What was the result when you uninstalled/reinstalled on the same machine?